# Can I CALL a stored procedure as the SELECT clause in a WITH statement?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

The usual form of a WITH statement is

```
WITH myrecs(field1, field2, field3)
AS(Select field1,field2,field3 from afile)
select * from myrecs
```

Is it possible to replace the select with a call to a stored procedure? For example

```
WITH myrecs(field1, field2, field3)
as (CALL myproc)
select * from myrecs
```

In this case, myproc would execute the select from the first example.

Regards
Ron Ventura

Comment: I think this isnt possible. You could return just single parametr, not whole select stateman.

Comment: No, you need to insert the results in table variable or temp table.

Comment: I don't know DB2 but in SQL Server you can use: `WITH myrecs(field1, field2, field3) AS SELECT q.* FROM OPENQUERY(linked_server, 'EXEC myproc') q) SELECT * FROM myrecs` where linked_server is loopback. Search for **`OPENQUERY/OPENROWSET`** in your DB

Comment: Consider wrapping the Stored proc in a user defined table function (UDTF).  I think that would work.

Comment: If your query returns the result of the (entire) `SELECT`, you don't need the CTE.  What version/platform of DB2?  Some of them support [table-valued functions](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0003493.html), like SQL Server; it returns a table, so you can reference it in `JOIN`s and stuff.  Or maybe you just want a `VIEW`?  If all you have is a `SELECT` statement...